# Major Themes in Plato's Republic

Tags: political-philosophy, plato

Please don't take my question as any form of offense.

I am a high school student and I accidentally chose a advanced philosophy course that I am stuck with. I am studying Plato's republic (Translation by RE Allen) and its connection to political theory. I am suppose to at least identify all the main themes (myth of the medals, plato's forms)  in the work and I am unable to do that. I am a very weak student in textual analysis as I had to use visual novels/comics of Shakespear's play just to understand the basic plot and those are not available for Plato. if they are, can someone introduce me to them as I would definitely need all the help?

Second of all, I am able to access journal databases like JSTOR and would anyone be able to introduce me to journal articles that can dumb down the themes for me.

Third and most importantly, would some of you experts here be able to explain briefly on all the themes that I should be looking for ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Besides my answer, I'll add this bit of advice: you shouldn't be so down on yourself! This stuff is hard, it is common when approaching a new work to use commentaries on it to help make sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's explained very well elsewhere, so here are a few resources you might want to check out that already do it justice:

1. Generally, Wikipedia has good summaries of things like this. See The article on [the Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Republic_(Plato)).
2. Stanford has a useful encyclopedia of philosophy. See the [relevant article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-ethics-politics/) for what you're looking for.
3. www.iep.utm.edu/ Usually is helpful too, but seems down at the moment.
4. I would also add that different editions of the Republic include historical context for Plato that might be useful.